# Importing multiple scss files

Tags: import, sass, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to import multiple scss files into my Vue2 project however I am getting errors on compilation - I suspect this is possible, its just my implementation is wrong...

My 'main.scss' file is imported into 'index.js' using the following line:

```
import './styles/main.scss'
```

Then, in my 'main.scss' file I have the following:

```
@import "./base.scss";// color pallete
@import "./variants.scss"; //variant colors using primary colors from base.scss
```

'base.scss' looks like the following:

```
$slim-color-brand-orange: #e87820;
$slim-color-brand-blue: #004a79;
$slim-color-brand-charcoal: #595a59;
```

'variants.scss' looks like the following:

```
$slim-color-brand-orange-light: lighten($slim-color-brand-orange, 15%);
$slim-color-brand-blue-light: lighten($slim-color-brand-blue, 15%);
$slim-color-brand-charcoal-light: lighten($slim-color-brand-charcoal, 15%);
```

However the error that I receive looks like the following:

```
 Undefined variable: "$slim-color-brand-light-blue-l5"
```

Below is an example of how I use the variables:

```
background-color: $color-error-background;
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? - Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as your background-color: $color-error-background is in your main.scss file, after the import statement.

Base and Variants contains variables. Any scss file that imports them, will be able to access those variables.

I think the issue may be the import into index.js.